# what is the proper connection method for wire to wire connection for outdoor ground bonding

Tags: electrical, grounding

I'm putting an above ground pool in the backyard and code requires that I bury a #8 gauge wire 4-6" all around the perimeter. Then it is to be attached to the metal pool frame at 4 equidistant points.  I'm unsure of what type of connection I should use to close the ring of wire around the pool, and again what type to use to attach the feeder wires that go from the frame to the buried wire ring.

I looked at direct burial rated split bolts, and wire clamps that seem made for connecting to pipe or grounding rods.  I've been searching forums for advice but so far I haven't figured it out.

Thank you

Comment: What metal and section is the frame made from? Does it provide pre-drilled/tapped holes for grounding/bonding connections, and if so, what size are they?  Is the pool pump grounded or double-insulated?

Comment: You might not find help because Storable pools are not required to have a ground loop, double insulated pool pumps have the grounding conductor included in the cord 680.30 through 680.34.  Are you looking at permanent pool requirements?

Comment: Also, what are the pool walls made from?

Comment: So the pool is a metal frame intex type pool, the wall is just a vinyl liner.  There are no pre drilled or tapped holes, I was going to just drill holes myself.  I hear you on the storable requirement but town is asking for it anyway...

Comment: @confused -- are we talking about a flexible vinyl fabric or rigid molded vinyl?  Also, how tall is this pool?  Does the pool pump's cord have 2 or 3 prongs on it?

Comment: three prong with gfci adapter, and side is flexible vinyl.  The frame that holds it up is metal.  It's 48" tall.

Comment: @confused -- can you post photos of the pool pump's nameplate please?